# Как прижать к левому углу <div class>

Tags: css, html

Добрый день, пробую себя в верстке сайта, для себя. Ковыряю чужой шаблон.Вставил код кнопок социальных но не могу прижать их к левому углу.

Вот css кнопок:

```css
ul.spicesocial {
  float: right;
}
ul.spicesocial li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none outside none;
  border: none;
}
ul.spicesocial li a {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url('http://zarobitok.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/social.png');
  background-size: auto 96px;
  border: 0 none;
  color: #FFF;
  direction: ltr;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 32px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -999em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
  <ul CLASS="spicesocial">
    <li CLASS="facebook">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.facebook.com/Masterskaya55-512373092185795/" target="_blank" title="facebook">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li CLASS="googleplus">
      <a rel="nofollow" href=" Прописываем свою ссылку на plus.google.com" target="_blank" title="googleplus">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li CLASS="twitter">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="Прописываем свою ссылку на twitter.com" target="_blank" title="twitter">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li CLASS="rss">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="Прописываем свою ссылку на Rss" target="_blank" title="rss">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Я вообще думал что нужно двигать его в CSS и значение  в самом шаблоне.

---

может так будет понятнее вот [сайт](http://masterskaya55.ru/)

Comment: float: right удалите

Comment: Чтобы редактировать вопрос, используйте кнопку [edit]. Публиковать дополнения в ответах не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй из CSS убрать

```
float: right;
```

а в сам див написать так:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs" align="left">
```

Comment: Намертво в той же позиции остался. Может вам дать сам CSS div classа

Comment: давай, или ссылку на сайт если есть

Comment: http://masterskaya55.ru/

Comment: Там если посмотреть, то и "валюта, язык, авторизация" тоже float left, но по факту они по правому краю, нужно наверно копать в области самого top-line(шапки где твои иконки)

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так у меня получилось с

```
ul.spicesocial {   
float: left;   
padding: 0;   
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное !!! Все получилось !!!!! Всем кто участвовал в моем вопросе, огромное вам человеческое СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.spicesocial {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Я уже пробовал, по этому обратился сюда ) Как была, так и осталась. Даже не сдвинулась (

Answer (score -1):

Поробуйте так

```
ul.spicesocial {  
  float: left;  
}  
ul.spicesocial li {  
  display:inline-block;  
  list-style: none outside none;  
  border: none;  
}
```

Comment: Как были так и остались (

Comment: ul.spicesocial {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}